# Google Maps API results vs place results return different names

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

I am using google maps to provide directions to multiple locations within a website. Users are in Japan, but are non-Japanese, so results should be in English.

In certain examples, even when the name is in the query parameter, a link like this [location](https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=35.6603676,139.7444553&saddr=Yotsuya,%20Shinjuku,%20Tokyo%20160-0004&q=St.%20Andrew's%20Tokyo), returns an alternate Japanese place name (主教座聖堂牧師館), instead of "St. Andrew's Tokyo."

This link is dynamically generated, so I can change the parameters if need be, but I can't figure out how to force results that look more like [this](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/place/St.+Andrews+Tokyo/@35.6727522,139.7156885,14z/data=!4m22!1m16!4m15!1m6!1m2!1s0x60188c8d46be1f69:0x2d281dbe9818c6db!2sYotsuya,+Shinjuku,+Tokyo!2m2!1d139.7164592!2d35.6902021!1m6!1m2!1s0x60188b97b4019f65:0x1ee2b2878130bcbf!2sSt.+Andrews+Tokyo+3+Chome-6-18+Shibakoen!2m2!1d139.7435644!2d35.6601882!3e3!3m4!1s0x60188b97b4019f65:0x1ee2b2878130bcbf!8m2!3d35.6601882!4d139.7435644), without hardcoding the entire link. Here is what builds the URL:

```
//handle directions links; send to Apple Maps (iOS), or Google Maps (everything else)
var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
$body.on('click', 'a.tsml-directions', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var directions = (iOS ? 'maps://?' : 'https://maps.google.com/?') + $.param({
        daddr: $(this).attr('data-latitude') + ',' + $(this).attr('data-longitude'),
        saddr: 'Current Location',
        q: $(this).attr('data-location')
    });
    window.open(directions);
});
```

Comment: Results to a query to what API or service? + Did you have a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization)?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the documentation. The localization isn't a problem. The URL like the one I linked renames and returns a Japanese name for the destination, and I am trying to figure out how to return a value more similar to the second link, in English.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. You mention a call to Google Maps API but you give an example URL on Google Maps website. So what is it that you need help with? If you are using the API then please update your question with your code so that we see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for any help, I appreciate it. Forgive my wording, I'm just building a map.

Comment: Right. So you are not using the API... I don't know how (if) you can control that on Google Maps website. Maybe have a look at [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#mode_directions) which has a directions mode as well as a language parameter. Or use the Javascript API, or maybe Android/iOS APIs depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at your sample URL `https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=35.6603676,139.7444553&saddr=Yotsuya,%20Shinjuku,%20Tokyo%20160-0004&q=St.%20Andrew%27s%20Tokyo`.

I understand that your intention is getting a directions on Google Maps. In the aforementioned URL you specify parameters for origin `saddr` and destination `daddr`, the `q` parameter shouldn't affect directions in this case. So, the destination address is just coordinate `35.6603676,139.7444553`. When I reverse geocode this coordinate I get the 'Japan, 〒105-0011 Tōkyō-to, Minato-ku, Shibakōen, 3 Chome−6−１８ 主教座聖堂牧師館' address as shown in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D35.660368%252C139.744455

The `主教座聖堂牧師館` corresponds to premise address component and I suspect it is not translated to English in Google database, because web service call with language set to English returns this component in original language as well

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.6603676%2C139.7444553&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

If your destination should be St. Andrew's, use it as a destination parameter.

And the most important part: Google has **[Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action)** as an official, recommended and documented method to construct URLs. I would suggest using this API in order to create your directions URLs. These URLs are cross-platform, so there is no need to create different URLs for iOS, Android or web browser.

Your example will convert into

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Yotsuya,%20Shinjuku,%20Tokyo%20160-0004&destination=St.%20Andrew%27s%20Tokyo&travelmode=driving`

The result is shown in the screenshot

[image]

Your code might be something like

```
$body.on('click', 'a.tsml-directions', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var directions = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?' + $.param({
        api: "1",
        destination: $(this).attr('data-location'),
        travelmode: "driving"
    });
    window.open(directions);
});
```

Note I don't specify origin parameter as it is optional and in this case it should be interpreted as my current location.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It helps a lot. Thanks!